# Какая минимум битность вычислительного устройства должна быть для рендеринга 3d моделей?

Tags: arduino

подскажите какая минимум битность вычислительного устройства должна быть для рендеринга 3d моделей. Просто я хочу попробовать отрендерить 3d  модель на ардуино nano, понимаю что на это уйдет несколько дней или месяцев, и множество костылей для преобразования расчетов, но подскажите насколько это реально и в какую сторону с математикой копать.

Comment: У тебя не хватит оперативной памяти для вычислений. <pre>
Возможность реализации машины Тьюринга на конкретном языке программирования можно грубо описать как перечень требований, которым этот язык должен для этого удовлетворять: Конечность (нет бесконечных символьных множеств и пр.).
Фиксированное описание (формальность). Всегда достаточный объём доступной памяти — в идеале здесь имеется в виду неограниченная память, однако физические рамки не позволяют сделать память ЭВМ бесконечной, поэтому она просто должна быть "always big enough". Неограниченность времени выполнения — любая программа в до

Comment: Все зависит от того, что имеется ввиду под рендерингом 3д. Но вот люди пошли сильно дальше https://habr.com/ru/post/496046/

Comment: "Рендеринг – это процесс в ходе которого получается фотореалистичное 2d изображение, сделанное по модели или по другим данным"

Comment: Отличная статья с хабра!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно, такой проект [уже есть](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/finished-arduino-raytracer/271621/3), так что остальное - лирическое отступление с пояснениями:

Строго говоря, рендеринг - это получение значания вычислимой функции. Поэтому, любой тьюринг-полный драндулет любой разрядности с этим справится - не в разрядности дело. `AVR` умеет эмулировать вычисления с плавающей точкой, например, а [вот тут](http://dmitry.gr/?r=05.Projects&proj=07.%20Linux%20on%208bit) вообще запустили на AVR эмулятор ARM, в котором запустили linux и bash (Что? Да!). Правда там можно придраться, что автор использует внешнюю RAM и SD-карту.

И даже ограничение на память можно обойти, если готовое изображение отдавать через последовательный порт, а исходные данные закачивать через него же.

Так что фактически, это вопрос времени, упорства и желания. А в качестве теории и кусков кода рекомендую [вот это](https://habr.com/ru/post/248153/), просто потому что я там соавтор - там не про рейтрейсинг, а про классическую отрисовку треугольниками с текстурами, так что это как раз повод поработать над вариантом реализации этого на ардуине, раз рейтрейс уже есть.

Также в качестве веселых картинок рекомендую посмотреть [демосцену на AVR](https://www.linusakesson.net/scene/craft/). Там и анимация в реальном времени, и музыка.

Дополнительно. К контроллеру [можно приколхозить](https://habr.com/ru/post/406193/) обычную писюковую видеокарту (раритентную разумеется, под шину ISA). Тогда у вас будет достаточно видеопамяти под результат и заодно устройство отображения.

Процесс рендеринга с текстурами существенно отличается, например, *компиляции ядра линукса*, потому что его можно производить попиксельно, следовательно, на выход нужен один байт.  Так что если хранить входную модель и текстуру на SD карте, ну или сильно постараться и упихать ее во флеш, пожав все что только можно - можно отрендерить и с текстурами и с примитивным светом.

Вот как раз  скриншот [из видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RD5VO8o9bD4):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вверху видно время - 293 секунды на отрисовку 320x240 в 16 цветах. Очень достойный результат на мой взгляд.

Comment: Дополнительно можно подключить ПК к arduino и использовать сам arduino как просто приемопередающее устройство. Вопрос был не про дополнительные устройства, которые можно подключить к arduino для рендеринга 3D. 
Ты читал критерии Тьюринг полноты? Я вот сейчас загуглил один из пунктов.
Всегда достаточный объём доступной памяти — в идеале здесь имеется в виду неограниченная память, однако физические рамки не позволяют сделать память ЭВМ бесконечной, поэтому она просто должна быть "always big enough".

Comment: Автор сам не против подключить внешнюю память, но для wireframe-отрисовки этого не и не нужно. Автор не выдвигает требования и о наличии текстурирования. Более того, автор *вообще спрашивал не про память, а про разрядность процессора.*

Comment: Он спрашивал не про память, но память надо в первую очередь учитывать в действительности. Можно и на 4бит процессоре что угодно вычислить, были бы алгоритмы для этого составлены.

Comment: Представь, что рендериться будет будет что-то наподобие параболического зеркала с неровностями, на который падает свет., в фокусе которого будет шар,  Сколько нужно будет учесть точек, для вычисления яркости на поверхности такого шара?

Comment: *Продолжаем весело использовать демагогический прием "отодвигание ворот".*
Даже после того, как вам предъявили фактически работающий рендер на ардуине.

Comment: Еще раз говорю без конкретики о каких 3D моделях речь идёт в вопросе нельзя говорить о чём-то. А про битность вообще вроде потом добавлять стали в сам вопрос. Я написал, что памяти не хватит, так как для моего понимания 1/2 кбайта ОЗУ - это вообще недостаточный объём данных для хранения исходных данных к вычислениям, что именно там делали для того, чтобы как-то отрендерить достаточно сложную модель в 64x64 картинку мне неясно. Возможно модель специально была подобрана под возможности ардуино предельные. Там в сообщениях четко описывают все особенности модели, поэтому такое мнение у меня.

Comment: Еще бы он исходники показал этой программы, но там вместо этого только ссылка на платный курс по МК. У автора оригинального видео в смысле. Это другое видео.

Comment: STM вообще по функционалу на порядок мощнее ардуино нано.
Module specifications:
Model: STM32F103C8T6
Core: ARM 32 Cortex-M3 CPU
72MHz working frequency
64K or 128K flash memory
20K SRAM

Comment: на видео arduino pro mini, а не nano вообще.

Comment: В первом проекте, на который я сослался, исходники лежат в [зипуне](https://forum.arduino.cc/uploads/short-url/n8jLXQnn6OIaa4lZS7xThj2qYjA.zip).
В описании к видео, на которое я ссылаюсь, никаких ссылок на платные ресурсы я не нашел. Да и даже если это видео - фейк от начала и до конца, у автора топика есть возможность это проверить или опровергнуть.

Comment: Исходные данные можно хранить в PROGMEM, о чем кстати и пишет автор картинки 64x64 - большую часть времени программирования у него заняло запихивание данных в PROGMEM, что действительно нетривиально, особенно если делать в первый раз и сразу на микроконтроллере. 

Я не помню, кому принадлежит цитата (Кармаку, может быть?), но суть такая - если лично *вы* этого сделать не можете, это не означает, что это не сделает кто-то другой.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQh-3kQtqBg я про это видео. На него ссылка есть при переходе на том же форуме на другую страницу. Да я вообще ардуин в глаза не видел. Насчет того, что можно красивую графику делать маленьких размеров знал давно. Но речь про 1/2 кбайта оперативки и рендеринг - тут просто понять охото это решение общее или под конкретные исходные модели взят и написан код рендеринга.

Comment: Если открыть файл detail_scene.h из [зипуна](https://forum.arduino.cc/uploads/short-url/n8jLXQnn6OIaa4lZS7xThj2qYjA.zip), там видно, что внутри хранится типичная моделька их треугольников - отдельно связи между вершинми, отдельно - cами вершины. Так что код обобщенный, модельку можно запихать любую.